# Let $X$ , $Y$, and $Z$ be random variables distributed uniform(0,1). What is $\textrm{P}(YZ < X)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z \sim \textrm{Uniform}(0,1)$ and be i.i.d.

How do I set up the integration for the calculation of $\textrm{P}(YZ < X)$?

Comment: This was already asked. Note that $P(X>x)=1-x$ for every $x$ in $(0,1)$ and that $YZ$ is in $(0,1)$ almost surely hence $P(YZ<X)=E(1-YZ)=1-E(Y)E(Z)=\frac34$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with simply 
$$P=\int_0^1  \int_0^1 \int_{zy}^1 1 \,  dx\, dy \,  dz =\int_0^1  \int_0^1 (1-zy) dy \,  dz = \int_0^1 (1 - \frac{1}{2}z)\, dz = \frac{3}{4}$$?

*Edited:* As pointed out in comments (Did , achille hui ...) the integral can be expressed in such simple form because, "fortunately", $y, z \in (0,1) \implies yz \in (0,1)$. If we had instead $\textrm{P}(a YZ < X)$ for some $a>1$ the integral would be more complicated.

Comment: If I draw out the curves, it appears that I need to have a two part integral because of the bounds?

Comment: Aside from the mysterious $1$ after the integral, this is an elegant solution waiting to be upvoted ;-p

Comment: @achille hui I've never seen a product of two variables as part of an integral bound before. Do I integrate with that bound any differently than I would do as normal? Why that integral bound?

Comment: Maybe add that $0<zy<1$ for every $0<y,z<1$, since this is the feature that makes the computation so simple? Otherwise, we could see monstrosities such as $P(2YZ<X)=\int_0^1dz\int_0^1dy\int_{2yz}^1dx$ appear...

Comment: @polpie there is no difference between this and other upper/upper lower bounds which depend on other variables. you can just integrate it normally. There is one catch. As pointed by Did, this bound is so simple because $y, z \in (0,1) \implies yz \in (0,1)$.

Comment: What is the $1$ after the $dx$? do you mean integrate "1" over the specified region. Are you using physicist's notation of writing the integrals, i.e placing the dx,... in front of integrand?

Comment: @achillehui Yes, I'm not fan of that notation but it helps to visually associate limits with variables... I've changed it to the traditional order

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simulation that might help you set up
integrals for an analytic solution. It seems $P(W < X) = 3/4.$

The histogram below
is for a million simulated realizations of $W = YZ$. 
[Addendum: Per @Did's Comment, I have overlaid the PDF of $W$
on the histogram.]

For clarity, the bivariate plot is
for 40,000 realizations of $W$ and $X$, with the appropriate
3/4 of the points plotted in green.

```
m = 10^6;  x = runif(m);  y = runif(m);  z=runif(m)
w = y*z;  mean(w < x)
## 0.750319    # aprx P(YZ < X)
```

[image]

Comment: FYI, the PDF of $W$ is $f_W(w)=-\log w$ on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Did: Yes indeed, added this PDF to figure in Answer.